# The problem with the explicit dynamic library

Tags: c++, linux, dll, g++, shared-libraries

I wrote a dynamic library in C++ random.so, which contains a rand_int function that generates numbers in a given range. I connected my library implicitly (via include "../shared/rand.h") and everything worked, but when explicitly connected I get the error "fish: Job 1, './example' terminated by signal SIGSEGV (Address boundary error)", below is the code of my program and library.

```
// example.cpp
#include <cstdio>
#include <dlfcn.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
  void *ext_library;
  int (*rand)(int, int);

  ext_library = dlopen("/home/nikita/Libraries/shared/librandom.so", RTLD_LAZY);
  if (!ext_library) {
    fprintf(stderr, "dlopen() error: %s\n", dlerror());
    return 1;
  }

  rand = (int (*)(int, int))dlsym(ext_library, argv[1]);

  printf("%d", (*rand)(0, 10));

  dlclose(ext_library);
  return 0;
}
```

```
// random.cpp
#include <random>
int rand_int(int min, int max) {
  std::random_device rd;
  std::mt19937 gen(rd());
  std::uniform_int_distribution<int> dist(min, max);
  return dist(gen);
}
```

```
// random.h
int rand_int(int min, int max);
```

`random.cpp` and `random.h` are in my "shred" folder, and `example.cpp` located in the "lb" folder, 2 these folders are in the same directory. `example.cpp` I was compile using this command:

```
g++ example.cpp -o example -ldl
```

Then I started it with the command  `./example`. Then I ran it with the command ./example, after which I got an error "fish: Job 1, './example' terminated by signal SIGSEGV (Address boundary error)"

I tried changing the compiler to clang, but it didn't help, `example.cpp` it is easy to assemble, by any compiler, but always gives the same error.

Comment: After `rand = (int (*)(int, int))dlsym(ext_library, argv[1]);` you also need to test `rand` to ensure the function was found. It is unfortunately easy to slightly botch the making of the .so and not get the visibility or naming that you expect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are calling `./example` without parameters so `argv[1]` is `NULL`.

Comment: Thanks, it helped, but, I tried to run the program with the argument (./example rand), but the program began to give me the same number every time I started, and it did not even fall into the range from 0 to 10. What could this be related to?

Comment: @Fuhrer_BMSTU some old  versions of GCC had deliberately broken `std::random_device` implementations that would serve up the same seed every time so you'd see the same numbers generated every time. This was mostly prevalent on Windows, but if your system is still rocking a GCC in the version 4 range you should take a closer look at the output of `rd()`.

Comment: @Fuhrer_BMSTU you are calling [`rand` function from stdlib](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/srand.3.html), not `rand_int` function from your library.